# Json array not showing output values

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I need help with my code. I have been looking for questions citing same issue. But I haven't found anything.

The problem is that it doesn't show anything in the output. (Literally nothing, just a blank page.) All the host, user, pass, dbname and query are fine. I triple-checked them.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    define('HOST', 'host');
    define('USER', 'user');
    define('PASS', 'root');
    define('DB', 'database');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result, array(
            'id_team'=>$row[0],
            'name'=>$row[1]
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I used the `var_dump($result);` and it show's me the complete array like this:

> array(134) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id_team"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=>
>   string(6) "Baddis"} [1]=> array(4) { ["id_equipo"]=> string(1) "4"
>   ["name"]=> string(6) "Combis"}

It's supposed that I have to receive an output like:

> [
>       {"id_team":"3","name":"Baddis"},
>       {"id_team":"4","name":"Combis"} ]

So, I don't know what I'm missing or what I have wrong in my code. Can someone help me?

**EDIT 2:** 
I used another simple code, but It's the same, I can't get more than X outputs. I have like 135 rows in my database, and I can only retrieve like 4 columns of 70 teams, If I remove a column i can get 80 teams, It's like a limit or max of characters or something... Still with the same problem:

```
<?php
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT id_team,name,cat,tel FROM teams")
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            $array[]=$row;
    print(utf8_encode($array));
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried $result = json_enocde(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)); var_dump($result); ??

Comment: @Kaylined - Just tried it, but now I get almost the same output as before but with incomplete db values, I only receive 1 letter in each row.

Comment: What if you do echo json_encode($result);?

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP Version >= 5.2.0? Is your json version >= 1.2.0? This function 
only works in versions equal or greather than those.

To check that, create a php file like this:

```
<? 
phpinfo();
```

And run it. The PHP version is the first thing to appear, at the top of the page:

```
PHP Version 5.6.25
```

And the JSON version should appear down the page:

```
json
json support    enabled
json version    1.3.6
```

Json support should be automatically included in PHP >= 5.2.0.

To check if the json_encode function is working properly, based on your code, you can try this:

```
<?php

$result = array();

    array_push($result, array(
        'id_team'=>"1",
        'name'=>"Test1"
    ));
    array_push($result, array(
        'id_team'=>"2",
        'name'=>"Test2"
    ));
    array_push($result, array(
        'id_team'=>"3",
        'name'=>"Test3"
    ));

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Here is the output this code should produce:

```
{"result":[{"id_team":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id_team":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id_team":"3","name":"Test3"}]}
```

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.29
JSON version 1.2.1

And yes, that code worked. But the main problem it's that when I call a lot of rows from mysql database, the array doesn't return my anything, an empty page... Im not sure if exists a max limit of characters or something in json or I don't know...

Comment: Hmmm you might be under an out-of-memory or timeout situation.
Try to enter this before your code just for the sake of testing:

`set_time_limit(0);`
`ini_set ('memory_limit', -1);`
`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '300');`